# Why was my question closed and downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, close-reasons

I posted a seemingly legitimate question and got aggressively downvoted right away:

[Code blocks based on the amount of indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54609922/4157407).

What is the reason and purpose? And how does the close reason "unclear what you're asking" fit my question?

Question image for <10k users:

[image]

Comment: aren't the comments clear enough? Posting here will just get you more downvotes

Comment: Are you asking *in general* why we have downvotes and close questions on Stack Overflow? Or are you asking about *that specific question*? The answers will be very different.

Comment: One immediate problem I have with that question is that you simply say "indents are better" as if that's a fact, and people who prefer brackets are wrong. Another issue is that you seem to be looking for a discussion of some sort, which doesn't really fit anywhere on SE. If you're not looking for a discussion, you'll need to make that a whole lot clearer.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. @TheWanderer I wish only it all would have been taken easier somehow. One fact is, that I cannot omit braces or, I don't know, hide them? They are there, occupying whole line. And therefore the level of distraction is *high*. (but opinions may vary)

Comment: @MikhailV they don't have to be on their own line. That's one style. You can put them on the same line as the expression declaration.

Comment: @TheWanderer that is how I tend to do lately, but the closing brace is still there. And in the end I am not sure what is worse. If the closing one is on a separate line the ovearall experience is not much better, even bit worse in that sense that I lose symmetry and visual match. I would prefer they are on a separate line, but somehow made tiny line height. But I cannot format the line in this way in any code editor.

Comment: @MikhailV: I would say that your problem is that you are way too stuck on one way of doing things, that you are not adaptable to the environment in which you exist. I've worked with languages that use curly braces for scoping, languages that use an explicit keyword for scoping, and even Python. None of them are objectively better than the other. You simply learn to use the style for the environment you're programming in and get the work done. If you can't adapt from whitespace to curly braces, how can you adapt from Pythonic coding style to C++ STL?

Comment: @NicolBolas Adopting to environment? But if you can improve things? Not that I have a good possibility at the moment to hide braces, but it would pay me back really good in the future, so I am ready to invest in it. It is just like say, buying a keyboard which has a feature that just saves you trouble, not necessary, but it makes difference. (And no, I stand by my point that the readability win is *enough* significant.). Getting used to semantics is not a big problem for me, I am using a small subset of syntax and mainly agorithms, functions.

Comment: @MikhailV: "*And no, I stand by my point that the readability win is enough significant.*" But that point rests on an opinion: that whitespace-delimited blocks are more readable. Basically *every other language* disagrees with you. What makes you right?

Comment: @NicolBolas "_What makes you right?_"  maybe the simple comparison? The level of difference between two presentation itself strengthens the confidence, thus moves this into the "truth" domain automatically, by the principle: "if I clearly see a tree, there is (most certainly) a tree there."

Comment: @MikhailV: That some people think that their subjective ideas are objective fact is precisely *why* we don't allow subjective discussion on SO. There is no productive discussion that can be had with someone who considers other ideas to be fundamentally wrong compared to their One True Way.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's ok, I suppose. Though feels a bit like trying to do micro-management of people exressions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why was it *aggressively* downvoted? Because your question is just... bad.

First, you're tacitly suggesting an idea that is prima facie absurd for a language that not only already exists but has literally *billions* of lines of code out there. The way you declare blocks for a language is the kind of thing you do *one time* when the language is being built, and then you leave it.

Changing something like this is like trying to change the foundations of a 100-story skyscraper after it's been built, without just knocking the building over. No matter how good you think the new foundation will be, it's *never* going to be worth the effort.

Second, you frame the question in the context that C++ is otherwise broken without this change. In particular:

> I'd say if C++ had this, then it's whole usage feel would almost go from "why must I carry this cross?" to something like: "ok, I can bear with it". -- so definitely not just syntax cosmetics.

Generally speaking, commentary of the form "your language sucks unless it does the thing ***my*** language does" is not very useful. And the downvote button gets used for "not useful" things.

Like that.

And third, it's just not well-researched. You (eventually) boiled the question down to "Was there such proposal on the table of the committee?" Well, there's a [website containing all of the committee's papers](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/), so that's a question which can be answered by yourself. I know there are a *lot* of C++ proposals. But that's why we have site-specific Google searches.

Comment: "you frame the question in the context that C++ is otherwise broken without this change". Am I really!?

Comment: @MikhailV yes, the post reads that way. It is generally good idea to skip "personal story/feelings" part of the question as it rarely adds anything to the post, at very least move actual question to the front and keep non-important text  to the bottom. Side note: before asking more questions of that kind (why X was not in language Y) I'd strongly recommend to read [Minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/) article which can help to see language design process.

Comment: @Mikhail well you talk about the language currently being 'a cross people have to bear's... So.... It surely feels that way

Comment: @Patrice To be fair - I was expressing this from first person, so it is my feel of it in everyday work. Something that I need to carry. Well other people as well, if they did not find a way around.

Comment: @MikhailV the general solution for people when they are doing something they don't like doing is that they change what they're doing; no answer on Stack Overflow will make that decision any easier. You will probably be more helped by a talk to a work councillor at this point.

Comment: I accept this answer. After some thinking, I conclude that it is indeed almost impossible that such feature will make it into C++ standard. Even if it will, it will last many years till there appear tools that make use of it. So it is more productive to search an IDE or translator that helps with this.

Comment: @MikhailV: You should also consider that Python's whitespace=block style is the odd-man-out among programming languages. The older guard of languages, C, C++, Java and C# all use curly-brace blocks. Scripting languages like Lua and Ruby use keywords for blocks, and JavaScript uses curly-braces. Even new languages like Go, Swift and Rust all use curly braces. As such, it is highly unlikely that IDE tools exist which make braces go away; you're far more likely to find IDE tools that make braces *appear* in Python code. Learn to live with it, and to even appreciate it.

Answer (score 17):

1. Are you actually asking to change a very essential syntax feature of a well established programming language there?

   Not a very good idea, especially not with keeping backwards compatibility in mind.
2. Do you want to discuss that as a proposal?

   Not a very good idea, since that might come out as an endless *opinion based* discussion.

---

My summary:

In my opinion, the question was downvoted as *not useful*, and close voted as *unclear* for good reasons.

Comment: for backwards compatibility: `#define {` :p)

Comment: @Jean Sometimes you appear like a sympathetic clown ;-)

Comment: I disagree about it being unclear. It's very clear (now): he wants to know if this was proposed. Granted, this is a profoundly stupid yes/no question (no, BTW, it was not proposed), one would could be discovered by looking through the [existing C++ proposals](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/). And yes, the very foundation of the question is the idea that this would be some kind of universal good idea. But it is a clear question.

Comment: I thought that such questions which need insight from the guys who created the language were off topic

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Er, it's kind of iffy. Sometimes we allow it, sometimes we don't. But in this case, that level of expertise isn't necessary, since it's simply a matter of looking through the existing proposals, which is public information.